# Search all Colomn in laravel get wrong value

Tags: laravel, search

I create a search function to search data on table , but this result on search is not like what i need . its because i cant/not know how to put i line query on where clause . this function like this

```
public function search(Request $request)
{

    $ipsrs_id = Auth::user()->roles->ipsrs_id;
    $cari = $request->cari;


    $ipsrs_aduan = Aduan::where('ipsrs_id',$ipsrs_id);// i dont know where i can put this line


    $query = Aduan::query();

    $columns = ['aduan', 'nama_pengadu', 'status' ];
    foreach($columns as $column){

        $query->orWhere($column,'like','%'.$cari.'%');
    }   
    $aduan = $query->paginate();

    return view('admin.report_sarpras',['aduan' => $aduan]);
}
```

this problem is i cant put this line

```
 $ipsrs_aduan = Aduan::where('ipsrs_id',$ipsrs_id);// i dont know where i can put this line
```

someone can help this ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is to filter Aduan with `$ipsrs_id`

and check the three columns' value that is like `$cari`.

use the **where closure** like this:

```php
    $query = Aduan::where('ipsrs_id',$ipsrs_id);

    $columns = ['aduan', 'nama_pengadu', 'status'];
    $query->where(function($q) use ($columns, $cari) {
        foreach($columns as $column){
            $q->orWhere($column,'like','%'.$cari.'%');
        } 
    });

    $aduan = $query->paginate();
```

Comment: its didnt work  ,  this line " $query = Aduan::where('ipsrs_id',$ipsrs_id);" i delete 1 words on this script not having error anything